# Performance multiple ajax call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a module in Javascript, that in some strange cases, will launch multiple AJAX call to a web service in a range of Ips. For example:

```
var _requests = [],
    _found = false;

for( var i = 1; (i < 255 && !_found); i++ ){
    _requests.push( $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.1." + i + "/service?action=example",
        type: "GET",
        success: _callback
    }) );
}

var _callback = function( data, status, petitionInfo ) {

    _found = true;

    var _requestsToCancel = _requests.length;

    while( _requestsToCancel-- ){
        _requests[_requestsToCancel].abort();  
    }

};
```

In terms of performance, is it necessary (convenient), cancel every AJAX petition? Or it is irrelevant? When one ip responses, no other ip will do it. Putting a low timeout would be better for performance?

Comment: Be aware that cancelling the AJAX request is only effective for releasing resources on the client. Given your example, the server will still be flooded with 255 requests. It's the equivalent of stopping a bullet after it being fired by destroying the gun.

Comment: I forgot in the for loop the condition. I have updated it: `(i < 255 && !found)`. With this check when a response is found, no new request is made. But I think is better try to abort which were launched. I was not sure.

Comment: That `found` flag is redundant as all the requests will be fired long before any response is received.

Comment: Yes, it is a paranoic flag. I agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already started the requests, each server will receive a request.

I'm assuming however that only one will respond and the others will time out. In which case I would recomend cancelling the other requests to save resources on the client.

Comment: I cancel the requests on the array, but I was asking myself, if it would impact in performance in Javascript. In the rest of cases, no callback error is provided, but I suppose that although no callback error is provided, jQuery internally receives the response. I am not sure if timeout for request would impact in performance.

Comment: jQuery internally uses the normal XHR object, so will still receive the error. However it won't pass it back to you unless you have an error handler. I would abort the connections as if there is no service it will have to wait rather a while, which means you have 254 connections still waiting.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your explanation.